# jQuery UI Sortable - Tables in IE 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I've got a sortable table and it's not working as it should in IE 7

As soon as i start the drag, the tr jumps to the top of it's containment element.

In a table with 2 rows, if i move the bottom above the top and drop, it drops back into the bottom row. Likewise, dragging top to bottom stills drops to the top.

Below is my code, any ideas?

```
$("#trauma-list tbody").sortable({
                helper: fixHelper,
                axis: 'y',
                containment: ".table-overlay",
                opacity: 0.7,
                items: 'tr',
                //revert: true,
                //placeholder: "sortable-placeholder",
                start: function( event, ui ) {
                    interval = clearInterval(interval); //Clear the interval so table is not refreshed while dragging
                },
                stop: function( event, ui ) {
                    var list = [];
                    $('#trauma-list tbody tr.case').each(function(){
                        $(this).find('.position').html($(this).index()+1);
                        list.push([($(this).data('patientcaseorderid')), ($(this).index()+1)]);
                    });
                    updatePosition(list);
                    interval = setInterval(loadList , 20000); //Restart the table refresh interval
                }
            }).disableSelection();
//Maintain cell sizes when sorting table rows
        var fixHelper = function(e, ui) {
            console.log(ui);
            ui.children().each(function() {
                $(this).width($(this).width());
                $(this).height($(this).height());
            });
            return ui;
        };
```

Comment: I'm not having the same problem. Have you tried removing some of those modifications you've done to it to narrow down the problem?